# AllJoyn vs MQTT - what is the difference?

Tags: protocols, mqtt, alljoyn

[AllJoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org/) and [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) are both open source projects for Internet of Things interoperability, both provide an event bus and a router/broker to connect devices. What is the difference? Are they compatible? Which standard should I use to implement my future-proof IoT device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AllSeen Alliance's AllJoyn project is open source proximal IoT.  It is usually a mesh topology.
MQTT is open source cloud IoT that works well on mobile and satellite networks.  It is pub/sub with topics.
They are complementary, in fact IBM is working on a MQTT plug-in for AllJoyn's gateway agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about that in [AllJoyn Adds Human Touch to the Internet of Things](http://www.iotworld.com/author.asp?section_id=3224). However, it seems that AllJoyn to be younger that MQTT, so for the second protocol is possible to found more documentation and frameworks.

Comment: There is no mention of MQTT in this article. I am asking for a comparison.